# Getting and setting dict items via paths

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to have something more convenient to work with nested dictionaries that come from `yaml` files so I wrote this `DictIndexter`. Its `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` accept a path instead of a single key. Additionally the getter can also take a tuple with path and default value. The setter on the other hand is able to create new branches, but only when it's a *clean* branch. This is a branch assigned to a non-existing key. It wont overwrite another value.

---

#### Implementation

```py
class DictIndexer:
    def __init__(self, source: Dict[str, Any], set_creates_branches: bool = True):
        self.source = source
        self.set_creates_branches = set_creates_branches

    def __getitem__(self, path: str | Tuple[str, Any]) -> Any | None:
        path, default = path if isinstance(path, tuple) else (path, None)
        item = self.source
        for key in DictIndexer._split(path):
            item = item.get(key, None)
            if item is None:
                return default
        else:
            return item

    def __setitem__(self, path: str, value: Any):
        class Missing:
            pass

        names = DictIndexer._split(path)
        prev = self.source
        item = self.source
        for key in names[:-1]:
            item = item.get(key, Missing())
            match item:
                case dict():
                    prev = item
                case Missing():
                    if self.set_creates_branches:
                        prev[key] = {}
                    else:
                        raise KeyError(f"Cannot create branch '{key}. Disabled")
                case _:
                    raise KeyError(f"Cannot overwrite '{key}.")
        else:
            item[names[-1]] = value

    @staticmethod
    def _split(path: str) -> List[str]:
        return re.split(r"[/\\]", path)
```

---

#### Tests

With `pytest` I made sure that the following features work:

```py
def test_can_get_item_by_path():
    data = {
        "foo": {
            "bar": "baz"
        }
    }

    assert DictIndexer(data)["foo/bar"] == "baz"


def test_gets_null_when_last_name_does_not_exist():
    data = {
        "foo": {
            "bar": "baz"
        }
    }

    assert DictIndexer(data)["foo/baz"] is None


def test_gets_null_or_default_when_middle_name_does_not_exist():
    data = {
        "foo": {
            "bar": {
                "baz": "baz"
            }
        }
    }

    assert DictIndexer(data)["foo/baz/baz"] is None
    assert DictIndexer(data)[("foo/baz/baz", "qux")] == "qux"


def test_can_set_item():
    data = {
        "foo": {
            "bar": {
                "baz": "baz"
            }
        }
    }

    DictIndexer(data)["foo/bar/baz"] = "qux"
    assert DictIndexer(data)["foo/bar/baz"] == "qux"


def test_can_set_item_on_new_branches():
    data = {
        "foo": {
            "bar": {
                "baz": {
                    "foo": "bar"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    DictIndexer(data)["foo/bar/baz/qux"] = "qux"
    assert DictIndexer(data)["foo/bar/baz/qux"] == "qux"


def test_does_not_create_new_branches_when_disabled():
    data = {
        "foo": {
            "bar": {

            }
        }
    }

    with pytest.raises(KeyError):
        DictIndexer(data, set_creates_branches=False)["foo/bar/baz/qux"] = "qux"


def test_does_not_overwrite_value_with_dict():
    data = {
        "foo": {
            "bar": {
                "baz": "baz"
            }
        }
    }

    with pytest.raises(KeyError):
        DictIndexer(data)["foo/bar/baz/qux"] = "qux"
```

---

#### Example

I currently use it to customize the logger cofiguration:

```
def _initialize_logging():
    import logging.config
    config = DictIndexer(assets.cfg("wiretap"))
    config["formatters/auto/()"] = wiretap.MultiFormatter
    config["formatters/auto/./values"] = [f"v{app.VERSION}-{os.environ['mode'][0]}"]
    config["handlers/file/filename"] = assets.home("log", f"{app.ID}.log")
    config["handlers/sqlserver/insert"] = assets.sql("wiretap", "insert log.sql")
    logging.config.dictConfig(config.source)
```

---

Why do you think? What would you improve?

Comment: You offer both {getter, setter}, cool! FYI, here is a nice package focused on the getter use case: https://pypi.org/project/glom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Overview**

The code looks good, properly typed, tested. This is a great starting point.

Here are various details can could be improved.

**Documentation**

Your code could definitely be improved with [docstrings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/).

**Imports**

This is more about the StackExchange question than about the code itself but providing the imports can make testing/reviewing easier for others.

```
from typing import Dict, Any, Tuple, List
import re
```

**Tests: splitting the setup from the logic being tested**

This is mostly a matter of personal preference but I find a line such as `assert DictIndexer(data)[("foo/baz/baz", "qux")] == "qux"` a bit hard to grasp. The test cases can probably be made easier to read if the `DictIndexer` was created as an initial step and then used to perform queries.

We'd get something like:

```
def test_gets_null_or_default_when_middle_name_does_not_exist():
    data = DictIndexer({
        "foo": {
            "bar": {
                "baz": "baz"
            }
        }
    })

    assert data["foo/baz/baz"] is None
    assert data[("foo/baz/baz", "qux")] == "qux"
```

This is even more relevant when `with pytest.raises(KeyError)` is used as you definitely do not want the constructor of `DictIndexer` to be the part raising the error.

**Splitting**

Your method to split relies on regexp. It seems slightly overkill in this particular case as you are using a single character for splitting and [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) would do the trick.

Also, you could make your code slightly more generic by providing the separator in the constructor.

```
    def __init__(self, source: Dict[str, Any], set_creates_branches: bool = True, separator='/'):
        self.source = source
        self.set_creates_branches = set_creates_branches
        self.separator = separator

    (...)

    def _split(self, path: str) -> List[str]:
        return path.split(self.separator)
```

**Getting elements with default value**

I find the way the default value can be provided to `__getitem__` slightly awkward.
My preference would be to rely on how things are done for [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

- `d[key]`: Return the item of d with key key. Raises a KeyError if key is not in the map.
- [`get(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get): Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

```
    def get(self, path, default=None):
        try:
            return self[path]
        except KeyError:
            return default

    def __getitem__(self, path: str) -> Any | None:
        item = self.source
        for key in self._split(path):
            item = item.get(key, None)
            if item is None:
                raise KeyError(f"Key '{key} not found.")
        else:
            return item
```

**`else` for `for` loop**

The optional `else` for `for` loops is a nice idiom which deserves some love and can be used to perform an operation in the case where `break` did not occur in the loop and the loops stops in a "normal" way.

In our particular case, there is no `break` involved at all so I'm not so sure that it is relevant.

**Tuple unpacking using asterisks**

Instead of messing with indices with `names` in `__setitem__`, you could directly unpack it into the parts you are interested in: `*names, last_name = self._split(path)`.

**Final code**

At this stage, the code looks like this:

```
from typing import Dict, Any, Tuple, List

class DictIndexer:
    def __init__(self, source: Dict[str, Any], set_creates_branches: bool = True, separator='/'):
        self.source = source
        self.set_creates_branches = set_creates_branches
        self.separator = separator

    def get(self, path, default=None):
        try:
            return self[path]
        except KeyError:
            return default

    def __getitem__(self, path: str) -> Any | None:
        item = self.source
        for key in self._split(path):
            item = item.get(key, None)
            if item is None:
                raise KeyError(f"Key '{key} not found.")
        return item

    def __setitem__(self, path: str, value: Any):
        class Missing:
            pass

        *names, last_name = self._split(path)
        prev = self.source
        item = self.source
        for key in names:
            item = item.get(key, Missing())
            match item:
                case dict():
                    prev = item
                case Missing():
                    if self.set_creates_branches:
                        prev[key] = {}
                    else:
                        raise KeyError(f"Cannot create branch '{key}. Disabled")
                case _:
                    raise KeyError(f"Cannot overwrite '{key}.")
        item[last_name] = value

    def _split(self, path: str) -> List[str]:
        return path.split(self.separator)


def test_can_get_item_by_path():
    data = DictIndexer({
        "foo": {
            "bar": "baz"
        }
    })
    assert data["foo/bar"] == "baz"


def test_gets_null_when_last_name_does_not_exist():
    data = DictIndexer({
        "foo": {
            "bar": "baz"
        }
    })
    try:
        data["foo/baz"]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    assert data.get("foo/baz") is None 



def test_gets_null_or_default_when_middle_name_does_not_exist():
    data = DictIndexer({
        "foo": {
            "bar": {
                "baz": "baz"
            }
        }
    })
    try:
        data["foo/baz/baz"]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    assert data.get("foo/baz/baz", "qux") == "qux"


def test_can_set_item():
    data = DictIndexer({
        "foo": {
            "bar": {
                "baz": "baz"
            }
        }
    })

    assert data["foo/bar/baz"] != "qux"
    data["foo/bar/baz"] = "qux"
    assert data["foo/bar/baz"] == "qux"


def test_can_set_item_on_new_branches():
    data = DictIndexer({
        "foo": {
            "bar": {
                "baz": {
                    "foo": "bar"
                }
            }
        }
    })

    data["foo/bar/baz/qux"] = "qux"
    assert data["foo/bar/baz/qux"] == "qux"


def test_does_not_create_new_branches_when_disabled():
    data = DictIndexer({
        "foo": {
            "bar": {

            }
        }
    }, set_creates_branches=False)

    try:
        data["foo/bar/baz/qux"] = "qux"
    except KeyError:
        pass



def test_does_not_overwrite_value_with_dict():
    data = DictIndexer({
        "foo": {
            "bar": {
                "baz": "baz"
            }
        }
    })

    try:
        data["foo/bar/baz/qux"] = "qux"
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

---

**Edit**

Something that I had forgotten: now that `__getitem__` throws, one could directly use:

```
    def __getitem__(self, path: str) -> Any | None:
        item = self.source
        for key in self._split(path):
            item = item[key]
        return item
```

Similarly, we could imagine getting rid of the `Missing` class and work with exceptions directly:

```
    def __setitem__(self, path: str, value: Any):
        *names, last_name = self._split(path)
        prev = self.source
        item = self.source
        for key in names:
            try:
                item = item[key]
            except KeyError:
                if self.set_creates_branches:
                    prev[key] = {}
                    continue
                else:
                    raise KeyError(f"Cannot create branch '{key}. Disabled")
            match item:
                case dict():
                    prev = item
                case _:
                    raise KeyError(f"Cannot overwrite '{key}.")
        item[last_name] = value
```

Comment: These are great advices! I've learnt some new tricks and better practices. Thanks!

Comment: @t3chb0t I'm glad you like it! FYI, I've added an additional suggestion.

Comment: I like it very much. Code must be like art and now it is ;-]

Answer (score 4):

## Bug

I'm not liking some code that I see in `__setitem__`, so let's run a few more tests:

```
>>> data = {"foo": {}}
>>> DictIndexer(data)["foo/bar/baz/qux"] = "qux"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    DictIndexer(data)["foo/bar/baz/qux"] = "qux"
  File "C:/Users/aneufeld/Documents/Experiments/DictIndex.py", line 27, in __setitem__
    item = item.get(key, Missing())
AttributeError: 'Missing' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Yup.  Creating more than one missing path segment is definitely a problem.

```
>>> data
{'foo': {'bar': {}}}
```

It has only created the first missing key & dictionary.  So let's try a shorter test:

```
>>> data = {"foo": {}}
>>> DictIndexer(data)["foo/bar/qux"] = "qux"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    DictIndexer(data)["foo/bar/qux"] = "qux"
  File "C:/Users/aneufeld/Documents/Experiments/DictIndex.py", line 39, in __setitem__
    item[names[-1]] = value
TypeError: 'Missing' object does not support item assignment
```

Interesting.  That fails in a slightly different way.

Let's look at the code:

```
        prev = self.source
        item = self.source
        for key in names[:-1]:
            item = item.get(key, Missing())
            match item:
                case dict():
                    prev = item
                case Missing():
                    if self.set_creates_branches:
                        prev[key] = {}
                    else:
                        raise KeyError(f"Cannot create branch '{key}. Disabled")
                case _:
                    raise KeyError(f"Cannot overwrite '{key}.")
```

Yup.  We initializes `prev`, then we have a loop the update the value of `prev` at each iteration ... except when a missing key is encountered, something can be done and the loop goes on to the next iteration without `prev` being updated.

Wait ... no ... the error messages are talking about the `Missing` object!  This is not the bug I was expecting; it is an entirely different bug!

`item` gets left as `Missing()` and,

- if it was the last iteration we can't set the final key value into `item`,
- if it wasn't the last iteration, we can't look up the next path key from `item`.

When you create a new branch, you need to update `prev` to the newly created dictionary (the bug I thought I saw), but you also need to set `item` to that same newly created dictionary ...

```
            ...
            item = item.get(key, Missing())   # Intended action: update item
            match item:
                case dict():
                    prev = item               # Prep for next loop
                case Missing():
                    if self.set_creates_branches:
                        prev[key] = {}        # Create missing dictionary
                        item = prev.get(key)  # <-- Fix: Replicate intended action
                        prev = item           # <-- Fix: prep for next loop
                    ...
```

We can re-work this to remove inefficiencies.  Note that before and after this code block, `prev` and `item` are the same, so we can move `prev` entirely inside the loop.

```
        item = self.source
        for key in names[:-1]:
            prev = item
            item = item.get(key, Missing())
            match item:
                case dict():
                    pass
                case Missing():
                    if self.set_creates_branches:
                        item = prev[key] = {}
                    else:
                        raise KeyError(f"Cannot create branch '{key}. Disabled")
                case _:
                    raise KeyError(f"Cannot overwrite '{key}.")
        else:
            item[names[-1]] = value
```

## Testing

Tests are good!  I like testing!

But, are you really testing the right things?

```
def test_can_set_item():
    data = {
        "foo": {
            "bar": {
                "baz": "baz"
            }
        }
    }

    DictIndexer(data)["foo/bar/baz"] = "qux"
    assert DictIndexer(data)["foo/bar/baz"] == "qux"
```

Have any other keys/subkeys been added to `data`?  Any been accidentally removed?  Yes, the key you are setting is tested to verify getting it returns the value you just set, *but is that the only effect*?

```
    assert data == {"foo": {"bar": {"baz": "qux"}}}
```

Now we're testing `data` is properly modified.

Comment: This review contains solid advice that the OP would be wise to follow: when testing, don't assert so narrowly that you effectively assume your code's correctness. I re-learned this lesson recently. A small project I'm working on had accumulated a couple dozen tests that were too repetitive. I wrote an assertion-making helper function that most of the tests were able to use. I thought I was just getting rid of code repetition, but there was an unanticipated side effect: for several tests, use of the helper widened their assertion-making considerably – exposing a couple of edge-case bugs!

Answer (score 3):

Your `__getitem__` function indicates two conflicting ideas.

1. You call out `__getitem__` can return `None`.

   ```py
   def __getitem__(...) -> Any | None:
   ```
2. Your function cannot return `None` unless `default` is `None`.

   ```py
   item = item.get(key, None)
   if item is None:
       return default
   ```

   ```py
   >>> DictIndexer({"a": None})["a", "default value"]
   default value
   ```

Because of the code in the second item, your class doesn't work in a similar way to `dict.get`.
A fairly large Python idiom is [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP).
To easily get the same interface as `dict.get` is really simple with EAFP.

```py
>>> {"a": None}.get("a", "default value")
None
```

```py
def __getitem__(self, path: str | Tuple[str, Any]) -> Any | None:
    path, default = path if isinstance(path, tuple) else (path, None)
    try:
        item = self.source
        for key in self._split(path):
            item = item[key]
        return item
    except KeyError:
        return default
```

I can also see a potential for conflicting ideas on type hints - `Any | None` is `Any`.
I did things like `Any | None` when I wanted to make the class generic but didn't fully know how.
So I'm going to go through an over-kill entirely generic class.

First we can define a recursive generic alias for a dictionary of dictionaries or values.
Basically the dict tree we're interacting with.

```py
TKey = TypeVar("TKey")
TValue = TypeVar("TValue")

ATree: TypeAlias = dict[TKey, TValue] | TValue | dict[TKey, "ATree[TKey, TValue]"]
```

From here we can define a generic class which takes a `Tree` as input.
And we'll define `_split`'s type hints to remove errors with mypy.

```py
class DictIndexer(Generic[TKey, TValue]):
    def __init__(self, source: Tree[TKey, TValue]) -> None:
        self.source = source

    @classmethod
    def _split(cls, path: TKey) -> Iterable[TKey]:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"{cls.__name__}._split has not been defined")
```

And then finally use `overload` to completely type `__getitem__`.
There are two paths:

- no default specified so the type is `None`, or
- a default type is provided which we should union with.

```py
TDefault = TypeVar("TDefault")

...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, path: TKey | tuple[TKey]) -> TValue | None: ...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, path: tuple[TKey, TDefault]) -> TValue | TDefault: ...

    def __getitem__(self, path: Any) -> Any:
```

From here we can see the generic types for `DictIndexer` are inferred by the dictionary literal.
And we can see `__getitem__` correctly sets the correct return types.

```py
tree = DictIndexer({"a": None})
reveal_type(tree)
reveal_type(tree["a"])
reveal_type(tree["a", "default value"])
```

```
>>> mypy foo.py
foo.py:36: note: Revealed type is "foo.DictIndexer[builtins.str, None]"
foo.py:37: note: Revealed type is "None"
foo.py:38: note: Revealed type is "Union[None, builtins.str]"
```

Your `__setitem__` is far less EAFP than `__getitem__`.
If we ignore the "able to create new branches, but only when it's a clean branch" part we can make a very simple EAFP function.

Lets look at the edge-cases:

1. ```py
   >>> {}["a"]
   KeyError: 'a'
   ```
2. ```py
   >>> None["a"]
   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
   ```

So we can quite easily rewrite `__setitem__` in the exact same way we did with `__getitem__`.

```py
def __setitem__(self, path: TKey, value: TValue) -> None:
    *head, tail = key, *_ = self._split(path)
    try:
        item = self.source
        for key in head:
            item = item[key]
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError(f"Cannot create branch '{key}. Disabled") from None
    except TypeError:
        raise KeyError(f"Cannot overwrite '{key}.") from None
    else:
        item[tail] = value
```

Now we can change `__setitem__` to support the `dict.setdefault` like behaviour.

```py
try:
    item = self.source
    if not self.set_creates_branches:
        for key in head:
            item = item[key]
    else:
        for key in head:
            try:
                item = item[key]
            except KeyError:
                item[key] = item = {}
except KeyError:
```

```py
from typing import Any, Generic, Iterable, TypeAlias, TypeVar, overload

TKey = TypeVar("TKey")
TValue = TypeVar("TValue")
TDefault = TypeVar("TDefault")

ATree: TypeAlias = dict[TKey, TValue] | TValue | dict[TKey, "ATree[TKey, TValue]"]


class BaseDictIndexer(Generic[TKey, TValue]):
    def __init__(
        self,
        source: ATree[TKey, TValue],
        set_creates_branches: bool = True,
    ) -> None:
        self.source = source
        self.set_creates_branches = set_creates_branches

    @classmethod
    def _split(cls, path: TKey) -> Iterable[TKey]:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"{cls.__name__}._split has not been defined")

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, path: TKey | tuple[TKey]) -> TValue | None: ...

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, path: tuple[TKey, TDefault]) -> TValue | TDefault: ...

    def __getitem__(self, path: Any) -> Any:
        path, default = path if isinstance(path, tuple) else (path, None)
        try:
            item = self.source
            for key in DictIndexer._split(path):
                item = item[key]  # type: ignore
            return item
        except KeyError:
            return default

    def __setitem__(self, path: TKey, value: TValue) -> None:
        *head, tail = key, *_ = self._split(path)
        try:
            item = self.source
            if not self.set_creates_branches:
                for key in head:
                    item = item[key]  # type: ignore
            else:
                for key in head:
                    try:
                        item = item[key]  # type: ignore
                    except KeyError:
                        item[key] = item = {}  # type: ignore
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError(f"Cannot create branch '{key}'. Disabled") from None
        except TypeError:
            raise KeyError(f"Cannot overwrite '{key}'.") from None
        else:
            item[tail] = value  # type: ignore


class DictIndexer(BaseDictIndexer[str, TValue]):
    @staticmethod
    def _split(path: str) -> list[str]:
        return path.split("/")


# tree = DictIndexer({"a": None}, set_creates_branches=False)
tree = DictIndexer({"a": None})
print(tree["a"])
tree["b/c/d"] = None
print(tree["b/c/d"])
print(tree.source)
```

Comment: This is rocket-science for me, but I now see how powerful generics can be so I'll dig into that.

Comment: I'm studying your suggestions and I'm currently stuck on `Tree[TKey, TValue]` that I wasn't able to crack. You defined it as a `TypeAlias` (with a typo as `ATree`) from what I understand it can be either one of the tree types separated by the pipe `|`. What I don't understand is why is `Tree` taking two generic arguments? Is it because you use the first of the types in the list this is `dict[TKey, TValue]` as the source or is it becuase the types within the alias use generic types so you need to specify them in the declaration. I tend to think this is the latter.

Comment: Then in the last type `Dict[TKey, "Tree[TKey, TValue]"]` you use a string. I guess this is because of the recursion or self-reference. I'm typing it step by step in PyCharm and it recognizes this correctly. I think I've found it in the docs. It's called a [forward reference](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references), right?

Comment: I knew about tuple/list unpacking, but why does this work the way it works: `*head, tail = key, *_ = self._split(path)`? I run it in the console with `*head, tail = k, *x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and the result is `head =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], tail = 1, k = 1, x = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. At first I thought that only `k` would be unpacked into `*head, tail`. However, it turns out that the list is being indepenently unpacked twice and not processed from right to left. That's pretty unexpected or expected for a seasoned pythonist ;-]

Comment: This double assignment surprised me too: `item[key] = item = {}`. I thought I write it like `item = item[key] = {}` as this was more intuitive to me, but it actually doesn't work! Strangely it creates multiple nested dicts `{'foo': {'foo': {'foo': {'foo': {'foo': {'foo': {...}}}}}}}` when I debug it with PyCharm, but creates only a single key when I run the same statment on an empty dict in the console! This is pretty confusing, but I guess a case for SO.

Comment: 1. I prefix all `TypeAlias`' with `A`. I also prefix `Protocol`s with `I` (like C#) and suffix ABCs with `Base`. 2. Lets pretend `ATree` is `ATree = dict[TKey, TValue]`. When we're using `ATree` we're effectively just using `dict`. So when you pass the types to `dict` you need both the key and the value types. So because we've defined two generic types in the type alias we need to specify all the generics. -- An interesting side note is if you `ATree = TValue | dict ...` the arguments to `ATree` will be flipped to `ATree[TValue, TKey]`. Yes the string is a forward reference.

Comment: @t3chb0t 4. Multiple assignment acts from left to right. `item[key] = item = {}` assigns `item[key]` first, then assigns `item`. If you instead do `item = item[key] = {}` then you're doing `item = {}`, `item[key] = item`, which should obviously become the infinitely recursive dict you see. 3. Your result doesn't seem right, I get `head=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], tail=6, key=1, x=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. Notice `tail=6` not `tail=1`. As mentioned before multiple assignments act right to left. Additionally the resulting object in tuple unpacking _is the entire tuple_. We haven't sliced the tuple.